# List different subrange days from a date range with moment and javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates with hours:

```
Start: 2019-09-06 14:00:00
End: 2019-09-9 19:30:00
```

I need to list all subrange days (full or partial) inside the range, also with hours, in this example:

```
2019-09-06 14:00:00 to 2019-09-06 23:59:59
2019-09-07 00:00:00 to 2019-09-07 23:59:59
2019-09-08 00:00:00 to 2019-09-08 23:59:59
2019-09-09 00:00:00 to 2019-09-09 19:30:00
```

in an array like:

```
result = array(
0 => array(
   "Start" => 2019-09-06 14:00:00, 
   "End" => 2019-09-06 23:59:59
),
1 => array(
   "Start" => 2019-09-07 00:00:00, 
   "End" => 2019-09-07 23:59:59
),
...
)
```

I have found similar script to list all days like:

```
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = [];

    var currDate = moment(startDate).startOf('day');
    var lastDate = moment(endDate).startOf('day');

    while(currDate.add(1, 'days').diff(lastDate) < 0) {
        console.log(currDate.toDate());
        dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());
    }

    return dates;
};
```

But it doesn't consider hour and subrange like I need.

I'd like to use moment.js to simplify all the job but i'm not sure how to start with.
Any suggest how to "recognize" different days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a fun exercise with moment.js. The idea is to collect list of day starts and ends separately:

```
var start = "2019-09-06 14:00:00";
var end = "2019-09-9 19:30:00";

var startMoment = moment(start);
var endMoment = moment(end);

var starts = [startMoment.toDate()];
var ends = [];

var dayBeforeEnd = moment(endMoment).subtract(1, 'days');
for (var m = moment(startMoment); m.isBefore(dayBeforeEnd); m.add(1, 'days')) {
  ends.push(moment(m).endOf('day').toDate());
  starts.push(moment(m).add(1, 'days').startOf('day').toDate());
}

ends.push(endMoment.toDate());
```

Now `starts[i]` and `ends[i]` contains corresponding day start and end as Date objects.

One may notice a lot of `moment(moment_object)` happening. That is because moment objects [are mutable](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/01-parsing/12-moment-clone/), so you need to clone it every time you need to add or subtract some timerange.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load `moment` for that.

In JavaScript, the `Date` object has `setHour()`, `setMinutes()` and so on. You can get the current date, sum 24 hours and get the date again.

For example:

```js
function getRanges(start, end) {
    start = new Date(start).getTime(); // Sanitize input
    end = new Date(end).getTime();
    
    var list = [];
    var current = start;
    while(current < end) {
        var date = new Date(current); // Get current date
        
        // Set the date to just before midnight.
        date.setHours(23);
        date.setMinutes(59);
        date.setSeconds(59);
        date.setMilliseconds(999);
        
        // Now you have the next element in the range
        var next = date.getTime();
        
        if (next > end) { // Don't surpass the end
            next = end;
        }
        
        // create a range using the current and the end of the day before midnight
        list.push({
            start: current,
            end: next
        });
        
        current = next+1; // Go to the very next day
    }
    return list;
}

var ranges = getRanges(Date.now()-(7*24*60*60*1000), Date.now());

// You can convert them to dates if you want
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    ranges[i].start = new Date(ranges[i].start).toLocaleString();
    ranges[i].end = new Date(ranges[i].end).toLocaleString();
}
console.log(ranges);
```

Comment: Thank you. Good solution without moment.js!